# Blender as a level designer

Tags: export

If I use blender as a world builder for an external game engine with GLTF2.0 as an exchange media I suppose I need to find a way to put lots of interactive elements to my worlds such as switches, turnable lights, openable doors and so on. What is the most convenient method to do so? I suspect, I have to make collection of stock elements with animations. After that, when editing a level, I have to put some special non-visual elements on my level with lots of parameters. Then, I have to alter GLTF2.0 exporting script to translate these non visual items to GLTF2.0 extension items. Later on, level loading routine in my game engine should replace these extensions with corresponding stock objects such as doors, switches and so on. Is my vision correct or am I reinventing the wheel or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly don't have to do this. Just export the objects, then you can animate them in your game code. As for animations, I'm not sure whether those can be exported in glTF, but there should be a way to export them somehow.

Comment: Yes, I can export objects, I can even export objects with working animations in GLTF2. But how can I design a whole level in blender with, say, triggers? I can only think or non-visual objects with parameters, but I'm not sure how to define them in Blender terms.

Comment: Triggers? That's probably something you'll have to do in your game code, unless you want to use Blender itself as a game engine (the BGE).

Comment: And how do I position trigger (say, pushable button) in my level? Game code should know coordinates of a button within a level plus its initial state, I suppose.

Comment: Uh ... however you would position any object in the game. I don't really know how to help you with that.

Comment: I think I need some invisible placeholder objects, so export script could distinguish them. Of course, I can use cubes with special macro names, but i'm not sure if there could be anything more convenient.

Comment: Can't you just use the object names?

Comment: I could. But I'm making a framework for other less technically savvy people, so I'm trying to make it more user friendly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68972/discussion-between-seaturtle-and-minor-threat).